# Plotting a Highcharts Heat map from irregular data

Tags: highcharts, heatmap

I need to get a heat map that looks somehow like [this chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICkJP.png).

It should be done using the [Highcharts Heat Map](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/heatmap-canvas).

The thing with this case is the nature of the data to be plotted, which is included in [this link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tZ9TUExEqPSGyl1tzYuhQZbntPHbn1b5/view?usp=sharing)

This data comes from marine vehicles that perform repeated measurements at differents depth for a given parameter lets say. We could have for example:

**2018-05-25 10:34:38.500,0.793,19.1935**

2018-05-25 10:35:02.660,1.102,19.1851
2018-05-25 10:35:27.040,1.521,19.1792
2018-05-25 10:35:51.240,1.946,19.1808
2018-05-25 10:36:15.400,2.377,19.1745
2018-05-25 10:36:39.600,2.802,19.1726
2018-05-25 10:37:03.740,3.233,19.1703
2018-05-25 10:37:28.010,3.651,19.1615
2018-05-25 10:37:52.150,4.087,19.1645
2018-05-25 10:38:16.310,4.516,19.0939
2018-05-25 10:38:40.520,4.954,19.0345
**2018-05-25 11:39:10.810,0.773,19.2568**

2018-05-25 11:39:35.030,1.187,19.2086
2018-05-25 11:39:59.190,1.601,19.1897
2018-05-25 11:40:23.440,2.033,19.1781
2018-05-25 11:40:47.600,2.467,19.1768
2018-05-25 11:41:11.760,2.901,19.1645

...
**2018-06-11 06:50:39.000,0.804,19.7988**

2018-06-11 06:51:03.140,1.26,19.7534
2018-06-11 06:51:27.300,1.738,19.3438
2018-06-11 06:51:51.430,2.221,19.3161
2018-06-11 06:52:15.660,2.705,19.264
...

Where the columns are the timestamp in human readable format, the depth and the temperature.

For any given day, the depth of the measurements varies and also the number of measurements. Within the same day the vehicle go a few times to the surface and then go back to dive again.

can someone please point me the right direction to start?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have listed some requirements and details about your data, but not any issues or questions. "Help would be really appreciated" - do you mean, "can someone please do this for me?". If you show off what you have tried, and where you are stuck, you will generally get help very quickly.

Comment: The right direction to start; convert all your timestamps to milliseconds since 1970, e.g. `new Date('2018-05-25 10:34:38.500').getTime()`. If they are not sorted, sort them either before or after. Put them in this structure: `[{x: new Date('2018-05-25 10:34:38.500').getTime(), y: 0.793}, {x: new Date('2018-05-25 10:35:02.660').getTime(), y: 1.102}, ...]` and use that as data for series 1, then do this for the data for series 2: `[{x: new Date('2018-05-25 10:34:38.500').getTime(), y: 19.1935}, {x: new Date('2018-05-25 10:35:02.660').getTime(), y: 19.1851}, ...]` . Then use 2 axis and plot.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your help [ewolden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8376046/ewolden). After your first comment i tried modifying the higcharts jsfiddle for large heatmaps and get this [working heatmap](https://jsfiddle.net/ordicu85/fvgm3dca/).  But it contains tiny white areas, which doesnt happen in the [server version](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZOXk67Yjcosa4xQidvOFROvuLbmDFwhx/view?usp=sharing) of the chart using maplotlib and python, from the same data.

Comment: No problem, seems like you got it working well. I don't have much experience with heatmaps in hgihchart, that said, I found this: `rowsize` which I think might suit your needs, example with rowsize 3: https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/fvgm3dca/26/. I think this is the same as matplotlib would do, just widen the rows until there are no gaps. Ohh, and I deleted a bunch of rows, too slow too work with so much data while trying out stuff.

Comment: Excellent man, the [rowsize](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.heatmap.rowsize) parameter did the work. Im not used to use stackoverflow for asking questions, will remember your advices for the future regarding the way we ask for help. Thank u very much.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

With the help of [ewolden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8376046/ewolden), got this working solution. See [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ordicu85/fvgm3dca/).

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

data: {
    csv: document.getElementById('csv').innerHTML
},

chart: {
    type: 'heatmap',
    width: 640,
    height:480
    /*margin: [60, 50, 80, 100]*/
},

boost: {
    useGPUTranslations: true
},

title: {
    text: 'Highcharts heat map',
    align: 'left',
    x: 40
},

subtitle: {
    text: 'Temperature variation by day and depth May - June 2018',
    align: 'left',
    x: 40
},

xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    min: 1527244478500,
    max: 1528799894080,
    /*min: Date.UTC(2018, 05, 25),
    max: Date.UTC(2018, 16, 12 23, 59, 59),*/
    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
      day: "%e. %b",
      month: "%b '%y",
      year: "%Y"
    },
    /*labels: {
        align: 'left',
        x: 5,
        y: 14,
        format: '{value:%B}' // long month
    },*/
    showLastLabel: true,        
    tickLength: 16
},

yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: null
    },
    labels: {
        format: '{value}m'
    },
    minPadding: 0,
    maxPadding: 0,
    startOnTick: false,
    endOnTick: false,
    tickPositions: [200, 400,600,800],
    tickWidth: 1,
    min: 5,
    max: 960,
    reversed: true
},

colorAxis: {
    stops: [
        /*[0, '#3060cf'],
        [0.5, '#fffbbc'],
        [0.9, '#c4463a'],
        [1, '#c4463a']*/
         [0, '#3060cf'],
            [0.5, '#fffbbc'],
            [0.9, '#c4463a']
    ],
    min: 7,
    max: 20,
    startOnTick: false,
    endOnTick: false,
    labels: {
        format: '{value}℃'
    },
     /*tickInterval: 2.5*/
},

series: [{
    boostThreshold: 100,
    borderWidth: 0,
    nullColor: '#EFEFEF',
    colsize: 24*36e5, // one day
    rowsize:3,
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: 'Temperature<br/>',
        pointFormat: '{point.x:%e %b, %Y} {point.y}:00: <b>{point.value} ℃</b>'
    },
    turboThreshold: Number.MAX_VALUE // #3404, remove after 4.0.5 release
}]
});
```

Its based on the [higcharts JSFiddle for large heatmaps](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/heatmap-canvas/).
Like  [ewolden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8376046/ewolden) mentioned in his comment, watch out the use of the parameter rowsize, very important in this particular case.